# How To Deploy A Spring Boot Rest Project ByPassing Hikari Test Connectivity?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am porting my old Eclipse Restful project into Spring Boot 2. So far I am happy that my project is ready to deploy in production, BUT...

When I do "mvn clean install" the process fails since it tries to validate an internal IP address for my production DB server.

**Current Condition:** I work from home and, I don't need to test the connectivity on my computer, since I have no access to internal network, So I need to do a RDP to deploy the project.

**Question:** In Eclipse you can deploy any project without forcing to test the connection pool , can I do the same with Spring Boot 2? Can I bypass this initialization from Hiraki?

Thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvn install` by default will run your test cases, and as part of that it will bring up your Spring Boot app to run those tests.  Even if we disable the Hikari connect tests, without a proper database connection many other things will likely subsequently fail.

Is there a dev db server at work you can test against?  (Or can you set up  your tests to run against an in-memory db like HSQLDB?)

If you're very confident that you don't need to re-run the tests, you can disable them during install with:

`mvn install -DskipTests`